# Flutter firebase: Get data from collections and sub-collections created by different users

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

User A has a collection called `ADS`. In this collection, user B(the current user) creates a sub-collection called `Requests`. How does user B(the current user) get data from the sub-collection he/she created.

User A = Collection `ADS`.

User B(current user) = sub-collection `Requests` created in `ADS`.

User B(current user) to get his/her data from sub-collection `Requests`.
As u can see in the pictures, the uid'd are different

This is what I've tried but did not work.

```
class _MyRidesScreenState extends State<MyRidesScreen> {
  final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('ADS')
              .doc()
              .collection('Requests')
              .where('UID', isEqualTo: uid)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }

            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final request = snapshot.data!;
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      onTap: () {},
                      title: Center(
                          child: Text(request.docs[index].get('Driver Name'))),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Collection ADS]
[image: subcollection Requests(]

This didn't work either:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('Requests').where('UID', isEqualTo: uid).snapshot
```

This works. But it gives me requests from every user. That's not what I want. I want only the current user

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collectionGroup('Requests')
              .snapshots(),
```

Answer (score 1):

In the stream, passing doc() without any parameters inside it creates a new document. You'll need a way to access the id of the document, so that you'll have something like:

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('ADS')
  .doc(id)
  .collection('Requests')
  .where('UID', isEqualTo: uid)
  .snapshots(),
```

You'll have to structure your code in such a way as to get the id of the specific 'ADS' document you need to fetch requests from, or if you want to fetch requests across many documents you can look at collectionGroups. More info can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: from the edit, I used the collectionGroup as well, but it didn't work either. Can anyone help me how to access the id of the document "ADS"